Prevent VSCode from opening same files in different branches
I work with several git branches of a project and I normally perform the git business (pull, checkout, merge...) from the command line, then I launch VSCode with code .. This reopens all files that were open when I closed VSCode, and this is already a bit annoying, but it also opens all of them after a checkout, and this is really annoying. How can I prevent this? Note that the Window > RestoreWindows preference is already set to None (or equivalently I have "window.restoreWindows": "none" in my json.
